# How do I call docker compose from a service to control the host's docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a testing tool for work and this tool must spawn other apps. Running locally is no problem. I just spawn a new process from the tool. I'm trying to run it in docker and I'd like to know what's the best way to approach this.

My idea would be this app running in a service in docker-compose and I'd like call `docker run` from inside the container to add new containers to the network. Is this doable with `dind`? Can I control the "host"s compose from inside a service?

The real requirement here is that the containers are in the same network and I can set the hostname of the spawned ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I control the "host"s compose from inside a service?

Yes, you can control host's docker, you just need to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` into your container, for example start new container like this

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name some_conteiner alpine
```

or in `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now you install only CLI using `apk add docker-cli`(depends on the system, I used here Alpine) and you can call `docker ps` and you should see container that you are already inside.

Dind (Docker in docker) is another thing, it's to have more isolation from the host, because when you forget about stopping and removing some container it will be still running after your exit `some_conteiner`. When you have a dind it's running whole Docker daemon inside container, so it's containers in the container, there are also already prepared [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) for it with suffix `-dind`